# Why queryset attribute is only evaluated once in my cbv

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

I have a cbv with the following queryset attribute:

```
queryset = sorted(                                                                                                                                                                                           
         chain(models.Event.objects.filter(is_published=True), models.Seminar.objects.filter(is_published=True)),
         key=attrgetter('start_date'), reverse=True)
```

I do this because I want my view to work with both models (return all of them in the same object list, pagination, etc.). The issue is that the `queryset` always contains the values after the server reset. If I change anything in the admin, the `queryset` is not changed until I restart the server. I guess this is because the expression is only evaluated once?

By overriding the `get_queryset` method works but I want to know why it doesn't work by assigning it directly to the `queryset` attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is what happens when you define things at class level. Any code there is evaluated once at first import time, when the class itself is defined.

You explicitly evaluate your queryset, by calling `sorted` on it, so it is no longer lazy.

You are aware of the `get_queryset` method; this is exactly what it is for.

Comment: Ahhh I see. The **lazy** part is the key here. Thank you!

Comment: Technically it's because `get_queryset()` calls `queryset.all()`, which re-evaluates the queryset, and this doesn't happen if `self.queryset` is not a `QuerySet` instance. Assigning a plain queryset, even if it is evaluated, works correctly.